# Prefer web job or azure function for reading data from Azure Event Hub, with an incoming message flow of 5K per second

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Prefer web job or azure function for reading data from Azure Event Hub, with an incoming message flow of 5K per second

I have a task for reading 5k messages from event hub, I am confused whether to use an Azure function or Web Job and I would like to know the reason why one is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best material I have found and is very useful to choose among the both

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/09/14/azure-functions-or-webjobs/